# How to bind parameter to .then promise?

Tags: typescript, promise

i'd like to pass some arument to the then function properties at their current state when i call my promise.

Here is a code sample where we will imagine that getPromise return a number as result  :

```
let a = 0;
let b = 0;
getPromise().then((result) => {
    console.log(a + b + result); // i want 'a' and 'b' to be equal to 0 here and not 1
});
a++;
b++;
```

I tried to use the .bind() function in many ways but didn't get something working.

Ofcourse it's a minification of a bigger problem to focus on the technical problem i face.

EDIT:
I don't have control on the a and b value. It can change after i set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to pass it the values of `a` and `b`:

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 0;

getPromesse().then(((a, b) => (result) => {
  console.log(a + b + result);
})(a, b));

a++;
b++;

// mock getPromesse
function getPromesse() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(5), 500);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.bind` is the right tool to use here.

```
const wait = (value, delay = 100) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), delay));

let a = 0;
let b = 0;
wait(50).then(
  ((a, b, result) => {
    console.log(a, b, result);
  }).bind(null, a, b),
);
a++;
b++;
```

outputs

```
0 0 50
```

as expected, as `a` and `b` are captured by `.bind()`.

Comment: you probably meant `.then(console.log.bind(console,a,b))`

Comment: Thanks for this solution, which is another way to reach my goal which works !

Comment: @user633183 No, since I assume the OP wants to do something real within the function. Binding a library function doesn't have the same example value. :)